# Using the input in a Prompt Box and saving it to the database

Tags: javascript, vb.net, sql-server-2008, prompt

I would like to receive user input from a JavaScript prompt box, save the value entered and then insert the value into a database. I am using VB.Net and MS SQL Server 2008. How can I do this? I tried using an inputbox, but it didn't popup like a prompt box, but rather, I had to click on it for it to show up, which is not user-friendly. Is there a way I can achieve what I want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
<script>
var res = prompt("Please enter some data","default data");
if (res !="" && res != "default data") {
  location = "someserverprocess.asp?res="+escape(res);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I still need to fine tune it, but this is a great start. Thanks! :)